# Building a load bearing wall

Tags: load-bearing

We had a modular home set over a full basement. Steel floor jacks are lined down the center of the basement to support the house weight.

We would like to begin to finish the basement and want to remove some of the jacks.

Can we build load bearing walls and safely remove the jacks?

*We have the blueprints that show how much weight each jack is supporting.*

Comment: "*want to remove some of the jacks.*" That changes everything, except the fact  that you **need a structural engineer** to tell you what is required to carry the load, *unknown to us*, of the structure above.

Comment: We have the foundation blueprints that show how much weight each jack needs to hold.

Comment: To do this you will need a building permit.  To get a permit you will need plans.  For something structural like this you will need those plans signed by a licensed architect or engineer.  But even if you didn't need these things you WANT these things because the last thing you want is an improperly supported home.

Comment: If your jacks are not wider than 4” build the wall and leave the jacks in place it may keep problems from developing then no permits are required as you won’t be restructuring the building but redecorating.